# Using Tkinter while calling a function from button using commad to insert in entry widget suing function , it says entry variable is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

The error i am getting is

> search_box.insert(0,'Enter id')
> NameError: name 'search_box' is not defined

the username is **a** and password is **a**
i tried making the variable `search_box` global but it  did not worked
when i  click on `voice search button`

def id():

```
search_box.insert(0,'Enter id')
```

this function doesnot work and  the name error shows up
help to fix it

**This is the Code**

````
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root=Tk()
root.geometry('1000x700+122+1')
root.configure(bg='#8644f4')

def id():

    search_box.insert(0,'Enter id') #here is the problem , the error says search_box is not defined



#page after login
def page():
    global w2
    w2=Tk()
    w2.geometry('1000x700+122+1')
    w2.configure(bg='#8644f4')
    # search and register for patient
    search_PID = Label(w2, text="Patient ID", bg='#8644f4')
    search_PID.place(x=10, y=20)

    search_box =Entry(w2)
    search_box.place(x=70, y=20)

    getinfo = Button(w2, text='Search')
    getinfo.place(x=100, y=50)

    voice_button = Button(w2, text='Voice Search ', command=id)
    voice_button.place(x=85, y=90)

    register_button = Button(w2, text='Register')
    register_button.place(x=95, y=130)



    w2.title('Find And Register Patient Information')
    w2.mainloop()




def logcheck():
    uid = str(user_entry.get())
    psw=str(pw_entry.get())

    if uid =='a':
        if psw=='a':
            messagebox.showinfo('cool', 'login successful')
            root.destroy()
            page()



        else:
            messagebox.showinfo('Error', 'Password Wrong')

    elif uid=='' and psw=='':
        messagebox.showinfo('Error',"All Field are Required")

    else:
        messagebox.showinfo('Error', 'ID and Password Wrong')






#loginframe
logf=Frame(root,bg='#8081CD')
logf.place(x=250,y=150, height=340, width=500)

logintitle=Label(logf,text='Log in Panel',font=('impact',35,'bold'),bg='#8081CD', fg='darkblue')
logintitle.place(x=119,y=1)

username=Label(logf, text='Username',bg='lightblue')
username.place(x=135,y=110)
user_entry=Entry(logf)
user_entry.place(x=210,y=110)

password=Label(logf, text='Password',bg='lightblue')
password.place(x=135,y=140)

pw_entry=Entry(logf, bg='lightgray',show='*')
pw_entry.place(x=210,y=141)

login=Button(logf,text='Log in',bg='#8644f4',command=logcheck, cursor='hand2')
login.place(x=210,y=180)


root.title('Patient Information')
root.mainloop()```
````

Comment: i did it adding width but it doesnt work
you should try running the program first and u can observe the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be fixed by defining the `search_box` as global within the `page()` function.

```
global w2, search_box # Added global definition for search_box
```

And by shifting the `id()` function below the page function, it seems to be working as intended now.

The full code with these changes in place looks like -:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root=Tk()
root.geometry('1000x700+122+1')
root.configure(bg='#8644f4')

#page after login
def page():
    global w2, search_box # Added global definition for search_box
    w2=Tk()
    w2.geometry('1000x700+122+1')
    w2.configure(bg='#8644f4')
    # search and register for patient
    search_PID = Label(w2, text="Patient ID", bg='#8644f4')
    search_PID.place(x=10, y=20)

    search_box =Entry(w2)
    search_box.place(x=70, y=20)

    getinfo = Button(w2, text='Search')
    getinfo.place(x=100, y=50)

    voice_button = Button(w2, text='Voice Search ', command=id)
    voice_button.place(x=85, y=90)

    register_button = Button(w2, text='Register')
    register_button.place(x=95, y=130)



    w2.title('Find And Register Patient Information')
    w2.mainloop()

# shifted this function below
def id():
    global search_box
    search_box.insert(0,'Enter id') #here is the problem , the error says search_box is not defined


def logcheck():
    uid = str(user_entry.get())
    psw=str(pw_entry.get())

    if uid =='a':
        if psw=='a':
            messagebox.showinfo('cool', 'login successful')
            root.destroy()
            page()



        else:
            messagebox.showinfo('Error', 'Password Wrong')

    elif uid=='' and psw=='':
        messagebox.showinfo('Error',"All Field are Required")

    else:
        messagebox.showinfo('Error', 'ID and Password Wrong')

#loginframe
logf=Frame(root,bg='#8081CD')
logf.place(x=250,y=150, height=340, width=500)

logintitle=Label(logf,text='Log in Panel',font=('impact',35,'bold'),bg='#8081CD', fg='darkblue')
logintitle.place(x=119,y=1)

username=Label(logf, text='Username',bg='lightblue')
username.place(x=135,y=110)
user_entry=Entry(logf)
user_entry.place(x=210,y=110)

password=Label(logf, text='Password',bg='lightblue')
password.place(x=135,y=140)

pw_entry=Entry(logf, bg='lightgray',show='*')
pw_entry.place(x=210,y=141)

login=Button(logf,text='Log in',bg='#8644f4',command=logcheck, cursor='hand2')
login.place(x=210,y=180)


root.title('Patient Information')
root.mainloop()
```

---

**NOTE:** Also, as `id` is an existing keyword in python eventhough its not throwing any errors yet, it is suggested you change the name of your function perhaps to `id_` or some other name, as id is also a built-in function, and defining another id function, overrides the built-in `id` function, which may or may not cause errors down the development process. Even if there is no error it is generally a good practice to make the code more readable.